# How to create a matrix with n*n dimensions which is not an exact number?

Tags: matrix

I want to get a matrix like this:
[image]
It has n*n dimensions but n is not an exact number.
I have tried some functions like Table and Matrix, but they did not work while n was a symbol.

```
Append[Table[{0}, n - 1], alpha0]
```

Certainly, n should be a positive integer.
Actually, what I want to get finally is the inverse matrix of the original matrix.

Comment: It is a method, and it may depend on the brain to find the common results, isn't it? Can Mathematica do it without my participation after I finish the code?

Comment: ``NRoots`CompanionMatrix[Append[{a0, a1, a2, a3, a4}, 1]]`` or ``NRoots`CompanionMatrix[CoefficientList[a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + x^5]]`` if starting from a monic polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of *n*-by-*n* matrix can be created with [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) and [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html).

```
n = 4;
a = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> 1,
  Band[{n, 1}, Automatic, {0, 1}] ->
    ToExpression@Table["-\[Alpha]" <> ToString[i - 1], {i, n}]},
  {n, n}];
```

Then,

```
MatrixForm[a]
```

$$\left (
  \begin {array} {cccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \
1 \\ - \text {$\alpha $0} & - \text {$\alpha $1} & - \text {$\alpha $2} & - \text {$\alpha $3} \\\end {array} \right)$$

Comment: Great work! This method is actually what i need.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[mat1]

mat1[n_] := Array[If[# == n, -Subscript[α, #2], Boole[# == #2]] &, {n, n}, {1, 0}]

mat1[5] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -\alpha _0 & -\alpha _1 & -\alpha _2 & -\alpha _3 & -\alpha _4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
ClearAll[mat2]
mat2[n_] := Array[-Subscript[α, #]&, n, 0,
   Join[Prepend[0] /@ IdentityMatrix[n - 1], {{##}}] &]

mat2[5] == mat1[5]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: It works only in the form, but what I need is actually evaluate it, such as inverse it, calculate its value and so on.

Comment: @SuperLoop, please see the updated version.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way to get the companion matrix:

```
coeff = Array[a, 4, 0];
mat = ReplacePart[
 DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, Length@coeff - 1], 1],
 -1 -> -coeff]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -a(0) & -a(1) & -a(2) & -a(3) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

There is a formula for the inverse:

```
imat = ReplacePart[
  DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, Length@coeff - 1], -1],
  1 -> -RotateLeft@ReplacePart[coeff, 1 -> 1]/First[coeff]]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -\frac{a(1)}{a(0)} & -\frac{a(2)}{a(0)} & -\frac{a(3)}{a(0)} & -\frac{1}{a(0)} \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Check:

```
mat.imat == IdentityMatrix[Length@coeff]
(*  True  *)
```

---

From my comment, an internal function:

```
NRoots`CompanionMatrix[Append[{a0, a1, a2, a3, a4}, 1]]
```

Or if starting from a monic polynomial:

```
NRoots`CompanionMatrix[
 CoefficientList[a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + x^5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
With[{n = 5}, 
  SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 -> 1, {n, j_} -> -Subscript[α, j - 1]}, {n, n}]];
% // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3):

Table is easy to understand.

```
Table[Which[i - 1 == j, 1, j == #, - α[i - 1], True, 0], {j, 1, #}, {i, 1, #}] &@5
```

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -\alpha (0) & -\alpha (1) & -\alpha (2) & -\alpha (3) & -\alpha (4) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$